# How to control the line thickness of a drawn object with Grease P. (2.80)

Tags: grease-pencil

How to control the line thickness of a drawn object with Grease P. (2.80)

I scaled down a drawing, but now the line is too thin.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

- In `Object Mode` select the `GPencil` object, then go into `Edit Mode`
- Select the curves/vertices you want to modify
- Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or alternatively from the context menu through <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> → `Shrink/Fatten`)

Answer (score 2):

The stroke thickness can be controlled in the adjustment section for the grease pencil layer.

[image]